# Looking for a word related to justice

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "someone brought to justice.". She was (brought to justice) in the court.

Example: She was ______ in the court.

She is not guilty.
I am not looking for: justified or exonerate or convicted

Comment: Welcome to the site.  In my opinion this question would be improved with a little more information.  Can you expand on the way you hope to use the word you seek?  For example, is it correct to assume that answers should match the pattern, "She was ______ in the court."

Comment: @SabikaAmjad, why don't you simply use the verb **justify** rather than using **brought to justice**. Thus, you can say: 'She was justified in the court'.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal that has the opposite meaning. [Justify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/justify) means _to prove or show to be just, right, or reasonable_.

Comment: @SabikaAmjad "brought to justice", generally means that a person was found guilty and **punished**. Is this the word you are looking for?

Comment: **Convicted** [*Having been declared guilty of a criminal offence by the verdict of a jury or the decision of a judge.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/convicted) Please show and share your efforts at finding a suitable term. Please edit your question and explain if "convict" does not fit.

Comment: Casting my vote to close for lack of research and effort.

Comment: Given just the information supplied here, we've no idea whether "she" is innocent or guilty. So perhaps it would be better to say *She was **arraigned / tried / indicted** in court* (after which she might be found innocent, for all we know).

Comment: The person could be ***exonerated*** in court. As @FumbleFingers says, we don't know what bringing her to justice means; we need more context.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I think I found the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might say she was **vindicated** in court if her innocence was proven, or I might say she was **convicted** in court if she was found guilty.  You might also say the case was **adjudicated** in court, but I don't think you would ever say **she** was adjudicated in court.

> [vindicate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vindicate) -
>   verb - to free from allegation or blame

---

> [convict](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convict) - verb -
>   to find or prove to be guilty

---

> [adjudicate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjudicate) -
>   to make an official decision about who is right in (a dispute) : to
>   settle judicially

If I were to hear that someone had been "brought to justice" I would assume they had been **convicted** of a crime.  I.E. "She was convicted in the court."  Or perhaps better would be "She was tried and convicted in a court of law."

Comment: nice efforts Lumberjack!

Comment: I think I was looking for the word 'vindicate'. Thank you so much

Comment: @SabikaAmjad you should accept Lumberjack's answer. You can do this if you click on the checkmark below the bottom arrow. The grey checkmark will then turn green, and everyone will know that your search has ended.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a simple answer, but I think "judge" fits.

> verb
> 1.2 [with object and complement] Give a verdict on (someone) in a law court. ‘she was judged innocent of murder’
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/judge)
>
> verb
> 2.
>  b. To pass sentence on; condemn.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/judge)

The following passages are from two versions of the Bible from Revelation 20:13.

> "and they were judged every man according to their works." 
> [King James
> Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020)
>
> "and each person was judged according to what they had done." 
> [New
> International Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020&version=NIV)

I take these to mean to bring to justice each person.

Your sentence:

> She was judged in the court.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  To expand, in [colloquial](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/living-the-questions/201410/10-reasons-stop-judging-people) usage this word often has the connotation of an implied bias against the person judged.